# looping file names with txt and date in matlab

Tags: matlab, date, loops, text

I want to extract data from thousands of daily data files as shown below. How would I put them in a loop based on date with following file names? .7 in the end of file name is there with all files.
3B42_daily.1999.02.27.7.nc,  3B42_daily.1999.02.28.7.nc,  3B42_daily.1999.02.27.7.nc,   so on.....

Comment: Any code? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using regexp() to split and group those information, let's make one from the list you have there. Of course, you should get this list through dir() if a piece of working code but for now, let's start with

```
files = {'3B42_daily.1999.02.27.7.nc', '3B42_daily.1999.02.28.7.nc', '3B42_daily.1999.02.27.7.nc'}
```

Then you can make a cell structure to separate them out like so

```
names = regexp(files, '\w+.(?<year>[0-9]{4}).(?<month>[0-9]{2}).(?<day>[0-9]{2}).\w+', 'names')
```

Now, names should be a cell array where each entry would contain year, month and day separated. You can access the elements like

```
names{1}.day
names{2}.day
```

Hope that helps.